# How do I break a shower tray silicone seal with limited access?

Tags: plumbing, shower, silicone

I have a leaking pipe joint under my shower tray and need to remove the shower tray to gain access.  The side of the tray is sealed to the wall with silicone.  The top of this joint is covered by the bottom edge of the showerwall panel.

I've heard of a pneumatic sleeve or air wedge being used for this but can't find one long enough - the tray is 800 x 1400 mm.  Does anyone know where I could buy one or have any other ideas please?

Comment: Make a bent knife... worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but the space I have is too small for that. I can only think of an air wedge or tapping a thin piece of metal in from the ends of the tray

Comment: Could you thread piano wire under the tray and then pull it through the calk seal like cutting a windshield out of a car?

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go. The space is so limited though.

Answer (score 1):

I use dental floss , it will cut through just about any silicone adhesive/ sealant. Slip it in the crack and pull back and forth. I do this to remove equipment plaques on machines when updates are needed.

Comment: Ed Beal: using dental floss to remove plaques. LOL